# How to get json string for a searchHit?

Tags: json, scala, elasticsearch

Everytime I try to do `searchHit.sourceAsString()` or `searchHit.getSourceAsString()`, I get `null` back. But if I try `searchHit.getFields()` -> it will give me a `Map[String, SearchHitField]` and then I can get necessary fields back from it - which I don't want to do. That is because I want to use `Lift-json` library to parse "if obtained" `json` string from `searchHi`t in my case class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

`searchHit.sourceAsString()` will return `null` if you do not ask for the field `_source`.

This happens, if you have it disabled in your mapping (in which case you have to enable it), or if you specify other fields to return.

In particular, you have to pass `_source` to the list of fields in your SearchRequestBuilder. The default fields list is `[_source]`, so if you do not specify any other fields, you will get your `_source` back, but if you specify other fields, you have to add `_source` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the elastic search call `searchHit.sourceAsString()` in scala.Option something like: `Option(searchHit.sourceAsString())`. You can compose on this or do pattern matching as you wish.

Essentially, when you wrap a null in an Option it gives you scala.None type back. You can try it your REPL session.

If you want to compose, you can do this:

```
val jvalOpt: Option[net.liftweb.json.JValue] = Option(searchHit.sourceAsString()).map(net.liftweb.json.parse(_))
```

or if you want to pattern match then you can do this:

```
val jval = Option(searchHit.sourceAsString()) match {
  case None => // todo
  case Some(s) => net.liftweb.json.parse(s)
}
```

Comment: I ALWAYS get null back when I do searchHit.getSourceAsString(). My original question is not to learn how to parse, but how to get json for searchHit.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. @knutwalker's answer seems right.